# Lodash & Angular: Transform JSON object into view model

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, lodash

I am trying to find the best way to transform a large JSON object into a view model.  Previously, I had the model incorporated into the view, which is a bad practice.  So, now I have the model being generated inside of a controller.  I am using Lodash as a utility library.

My current design plan is to transform the JSON object into a "master" array that is accessible in the controller's scope.  The JSON file is being served by Express.  `ModelService` simply gets this file to make it available in the controller.

`$scope.arr` is the "master" array that I want to use in the view.

I also made the JSON data available for viewing at an external link since it is so large. [Here it is](http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cb2390bc).

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('ModelController', ModelController);

    function ModelController($scope, ModelService, _) {
        $scope.jsonData = ModelService.getAll();

        $scope.getData = function() {
            $scope.jsonData.$promise.then(function(data) {
                $scope.all = data;
                $scope.arr = [];
                _.mapValues($scope.all.parent1.clusters, function(cluster) {
                    $scope.arr.push(cluster.name);
                    _.mapValues(cluster.subclusters, function(subcluster) {
                        $scope.arr.push(subcluster.name);
                        _.mapValues(subcluster.entities, function(entity) {
                // map entities
                        })
                    });
                });
            });
        };

        $scope.getData();
    }
})();
```

This code is just adding `cluster` and `subcluster` names to the array.  I'd like the subclusters to be mapped to their parent cluster.  The idea I have for doing this involves transforming each `cluster` element into its own array, and then adding the subclusters, and then transforming each subcluster into an array in order to map the entities to them.  This seems tedious and inefficient. So, I am looking for a better way to achieve this.

It would be nice if I could add each cluster object to the array in one fell swoop without all the mapping and converting objects to arrays.  Is that possible at all?

The wireframe view looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esKQD.jpg).  The **Flex Cluster Title** is the name of the `subcluster`, and each number inside of them is an `entity`.

Comment: This really isn't as much an Angular question, as a lodash question. Also, what is `flexCluster`? Was that supposed to be `subcluster`?

Comment: Yes, I just edited it.  I think what I want is achievable with `_.values`, but I would like to reference the nested data in the view without using the chain syntax (i.e. `arr.cluster.subcluster.entity`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would move this processing into the service. It's easier to test, and keeps your view separated from your models (Controllers, are really more part of the "View" IMO when it comes to Angular especially if you're considering upgrading to Angular 2.0 in the future).

In Angular, I think the appropriate way to solve this, would be to use components (or directives) combined with ng-repeat.

The page template:

```
<!-- Page template, assume $ctrl is your controller, $ctrl.clusters is the data -->
<cluster ng-repeat = "cluster in $ctrl.clusters"
         cluster-data="cluster" >
</cluster>
```

The cluster directive template:

```
<!-- Assume $ctrl is the controller for the cluster directive, $ctrl.cluster is the cluster object. -->
<div class="name">{{$ctrl.cluster}}</div>
<div class="subClusterNames" 
     ng-repeat="subCluster in $ctrl.cluster.subClusters>
     {{subCluster.name}}
</div>
```

You might think that this is mapping your data too closely to the view, but *as long as you use components to display your data* (ie, don't put it all into one template) I think you'll be fine.

Comment: Thank you, this partially answered my question.  I added a picture of the view if that helps.

Comment: @GenYDeveloper, does that help?

Comment: Ah yes... directives would be a fitting solution.